# How can i check if char pointer is points nothing after allocated

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc

I have allocated memory for a `char` pointer in this code and I wanted check does it points anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *p  = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    if(*p == 0)
       printf("The pointer points nothing !\n");

}
```

And I checked that if it doesn't point anything. Also I print of pointer's length and it prints "3" although it prints nothing. What is reason of this and how can I check if it points nothing ?

Comment: The space allocated by malloc is uninitialized. It's not possible to check whether or not something is uninitialized. You should store values there before reading them back

Comment: I don't see the code where you *'print of pointer's length and it prints "3"'* - did that somehow get lost while you were posting?

Comment: Sorry, i have forgotten to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the check to check against the returned pointer, not the content. Something like

```
if( p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The pointer points nothing !\n");
    return 1;
 }
```

should do. Quoting the standard regarding the return values:

> The `malloc` function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.

The null pointer is returned in case of a failure, otherwise the pointer returned should be non-equal to a null pointer.

That said,

- The initial content of the pointed memory is indeterminate, do not attempt to verify it. Quoting from the standard,

  > The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and
  > **whose value is indeterminate.**

  That goes for your other question regarding *"checking the length"* of the pointer - it's pointless. Unless you have stored (write) some value into it - there's no point trying to measure the initial content, as it is indeterminate. You may eventually run into [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- The cast for the returned pointer by `malloc()` and family is superfluous. [It can be totally avoided in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, in C. Thus, using `sizeof(char)` as a multiplier, is again not needed, *per se*.